# Should SO have a feature of notifying other interested users/experts when an update request comment remains unaddressed within a specific time?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments, notifications

Users usually use the comments on the Stack Overflow posts to communicate and discuss the potential problems in the posts. SO encourages users to post comments in an answer post when they find an issue in the answer and ask for an update on the answer explicitly (e.g., “*Please replace method A with method B as A is deprecated.*”) or implicitly (e.g., “*So when using ArrayList::new the given key is inserted into the list?*”). Let’s name this type of comments as update request comment or URC.

The questions and issues mentioned in update request comments  (URCs) may be addressed in the next comment(s) or body of the corresponding answer post, or even both of them. However, there is no guarantee for URCs to be addressed. In SO, when a user writes a comment on an answer post, the system notifies the owner of the post, i.e., answer owner, about the new comment. Then for each URC, the answer owner can address it either by updating the answer body or by writing a new comment to reply. However, if the answer owner does not handle the problem, the URC remains unaddressed until other users address it in a new comment or in the body of the answer (i.e., becoming an answer editor).

I manually examined 688 comments posted on 200 randomly selected answer posts related to Java questions. I observed that half of the analyzed comments are URC. More interestingly, **while 62.6% of URCs are addressed within 24 hours, 28.8% of URCs remain unaddressed after a year**. One explanation for this phenomenon is that when a user posts a new comment, SO only notifies a limited set of users, including the post owner and other commenters if their name appears in the comment. So, if the new comment is a URC and the notified users do not address it, the new URC remains unaddressed until other users reach the question, see the URC, and address it.

To speak more specifically, let's take a look at the following requesting comments that have remained unaddressed to the time of this post.

1. The first comment, i.e. “What about if the smallest is 100001?”, in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27304654).
2. The fourth comment, i.e. “Current versions use TimSort which has …”, in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254155). Note that this comment is not a direct request, but an indirect request for an update in the post body.
3. The fourth comment, i.e. “OK, that was not easy for me to understand but …”, in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50133859). In this comment, the commenter needs more explanation.
4. The third comment, i.e. “This is really strange actually…”, in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30960103/intellij-java-home-variable/30960158#30960158).

Now, the question is: **Should SO notify other interested users/experts when an update request comment remains unaddressed within a specific time (e.g., 24 hours)? Or creating a queue for unaddressed URCs to encourage the community to resolve them?**

**UPDATE**: Please note that the goal of this feature is to help unaddressed URCs get addressed more quickly. So, the current feature that allows interested users getting notified about post updates is not helpful. It cannot determine if a new comment is URC or not. Also, if an interested user wants to address the unaddressed URCs, he has to turn on this feature for each individual post. But, by the proposed feature, the SO can show unaddressed URCs to interested users (according to their interests/experience), so they can address them. This feature needs these steps: 1- If a new comment is an URC? 2- If so, after a while (e.g. 24 hours) check if it has been addressed by the next comments or the post edit. 3- Notifying interested users/experts or adding it to a queue for interested ones to address it. Although the steps 1 and 2 can be done by users (by pushing the posts into a review queue for the community to edit), machine-learning models are also a good approach to do them automatically.

Comment: Stack Overflow wouldn't be able to determine if an "update request" is genuine and useful, so it would potentially send "spam notifications" any annoy users, so I don't see how such a feature would ever have a chance to exist. Like Larnu said, there is a feature where you can subscribe to a post. Notifying other, additional users shouldn't happen.

Comment: *"We manually examined 688 comments... We observed..."* Who is "we" here?

Comment: If a users wants to be notified, they can simply follow the answer. This way they will get notified once a urc is posted.

Comment: What higher level problem is this supposed to solve? What about the 50% you mentioned that weren't valid?

Comment: If you want to tell somebody, tell the poster that they haven't acted. Don't add work to curators. Anyway what is the point of telling curators? They are not the ones to "resolve" anything. They should already have voted appropriately, and all you're telling them is nothing has changed.

Comment: Why would people want to be notified that an "update request comment" hasn't been addressed (i.e. be notified that nothing happened)? If the user had evaluated the post and found it lacking, then they should have downvoted/voted to close/voted to delete/left a comment *at that time*. If nothing has happened on the post (what you're suggesting people be notified for), then there's nothing more for the person to do. Why notify for something where there's nothing to do?

Comment: If someone wants to be notified of things happening on a post, then there's the "follow" feature, which will add an entry to the user's inbox for most activity on the post.

Comment: If people want to be notified in the future that they should check the post, then they can set up a calendar event, or there are at least a couple userscripts which remind you that you wanted to revisit a post (at least): [Stack Reminder - Remind Yourself About Posts](//stackapps.com/questions/8163/stack-reminder-remind-yourself-about-posts) and [SOCVR's Request Generator](//github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/UserScripts/blob/master/SECloseVoteRequestGenerator.user.js) (on which I'm a primary contributor; "revisit" request types revisit the post at the scheduled time).

Comment: Why would there be a queue to address "update request comments"? Such things are usually issues only addressable by the post author, not the community. If someone is leaving a comment requesting an update, then they are normally asking the OP to add information or address a concern. Are you saying these "update request comments" can be resolved by the community? If so, why didn't the user who left the comment just make an edit? Are you saying you want some way for users to be able to push posts into a review queue for the community to edit (e.g. the defunct "Help and Improvement" queue)?

Comment: @Makyen thank you very much for your time. I appreciate your helpful comments. I updated the post. Hope it addresses your concerns.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, thanks for your comment. In this feature proposition, interested user is different from the interested user you mentioned in your comment. Interested users in this feature are those who are interested in addressing the URCs that have been remained unaddressed for a while.

Comment: If someone has an improvement they are fully welcome to create a new answer that includes it. Upgrade request problem solved!

Comment: Perhaps it might be unintuitive for some, but on Stack Overflow (and Stack Exchange in general), editing someone else's post to address a concern can be considered "conflict with author's intent", which is one of the reasons for edit rejection.

Comment: @Makyen, 
Thanks again for taking the time to comment on my post. I am a graduate student analyzing developers' behaviors in addressing requests. 
You raised several interesting and important questions in the post. I addressed some of them in the post body (in the update part). I would like to follow up on them here in the comments too.

Comment: Q1: Why would people want to be notified that an "update request comment" hasn't been addressed (i.e. be notified that nothing happened)? Are you saying these "update request comments" can be resolved by the community?

Exactly, I was thinking that the community (people other than the answer owner) can help more with improving the quality of answer posts on Stack Overflow, especially for those accepted and highly voted answers. And addressing update request comments, especially those that remain unaddressed (e.g., suggest new usage of deprecated API), would be helpful.

Comment: After reading all the comments, I agree that notification is not a good approach. However, given the facts that 1) many answer posts are edited by non answer owners 2) many update request comments are ignored by the owner of the posts, I still think it worths to consider potential opportunities for people who are willing to improve the quality of accepted/highly voted answers by highlighting or somehow listing answers waiting for improve. Meanwhile, automatically identifying those update request comments might help people quickly identify potential problems (deprecation, etc.) in answer posts.

Comment: Q2: If so, why didn't the user who left the comment just make an edit? Are you saying you want some way for users to be able to push posts into a review queue for the community to edit (e.g. the defunct "Help and Improvement" queue)?

Good question. I think we can suggest the comment provider self-answer their request. But also, they might not have the ability/skill to edit the post, so preparing a list (not pushing) for those who would like to find edit opportunities might be helpful. Again, please feel free to correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: After all, my main idea is to make better use of comments that propose problems/suggestions, as they might not be highly voted by the community and thus not easy to see (I did a statistical test on this).

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear why I'd want to be notified of this.

If you're referring to questions here, the OP needs to address update requests, not other experts, and I really can't do anything about the OP being unresponsive (other than [downvoting](http://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive) and potentially voting to close and/or delete).

If you're referring to answers, again, we really can't do the edits for the answerer because that would conflict with the intent of the post.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, we are referring to answers. There are already exist many answers that have been updated by users other than the answer owner. So, it seems that it is ok to edit other's answers. I agree that notification is not a good way to propose this feature. Perhaps, a specific page that shows the list of posts that have unaddressed URCs is a better way to show them to users who are interested to improve them.